# pyspark: Difference performance for spark.read.format("csv") vs spark.read.csv

Tags: csv, pyspark

Anyone knows what is the difference between spark.read.format("csv") vs spark.read.csv?

Some say "spark.read.csv" is an alias of "spark.read.format("csv")", but I saw a difference between the 2. I did an experiment executing each command below with a new pyspark session so that there is no caching.

DF1 took 42 secs while DF2 took just 10 secs. The csv file is 60+ GB.

```
DF1 = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("hdfs://bda-ns/user/project/xxx.csv")

DF2 = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("hdfs://bda-ns/user/project/xxx.csv")
```

The reason why I dig on this issue was because I have need to do a union on 2 dataframes after filter and then write back to hdfs and it took super long time to write (still writing after 16 hrs....)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically they are totally the same when you call one of them. But in you implementations are difference

With DF1, you add **inferSchema** option, it will slow down the process, that explains why DF1 took more time than the second

*inferSchema: automatically infers column types. It requires one extra pass over the data and is false by default,* [Detail document](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv#features)

Comment: Can someone please help me out, in what scenarios we should use spark.read.csv("path") and  spark.read.format("csv").load("path")?

Comment: @Gopesh They are totally similar, but imaging you want to load different file format according to logic, ```spark.read.format("csv" if SOMETHING else "ORC").load("path")```, it is more readability than when you use if else for ```spark.read.csv("path")```

Comment: @DuyNguyen if the infer schema is false by default but we don't pass a schema then how does it guess a schema?