# How does inferSchema for PySpark really work?

Tags: python, pyspark, etl, data-processing

Reading the documentation https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html#data-source-option, it is very clear that inferSchema "Infers the input schema automatically from data" however, my code is not working to infer the data types. I have even tried enforceSchema, but nothing worked.
[image]
In Excel, I notice all the data is 'General" type; is that the reason behind the hiccup?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark Option: inferSchema vs header = true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56927329/spark-option-inferschema-vs-header-true)

Comment: @BeRT2me unfortunately, no. I came across that post before I posted my question. I tried removing the header argument, tried 'enforceSchema'...nothing is working. All the data is being imported as string types

Comment: what does your csv file look like?

Comment: @ScootCork it's 9GiB. 65 columns and 3M+ rows

Comment: Could you provide a sample to reproduce?

Comment: @ScootCork I do not know how to do that, but will look it up. However, here is the URL with the data in the meantime: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/ananaymital/us-used-cars-dataset