# Unable to infer schema with spark read excel parser plugin

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When I run the below read options to load excel file into a dataframe , it gives me below error ,

**ExcelParserOptionsException: Unable to parse options:
Invalid option 'inferschema', did you mean 'enforceSchema'?**

Am I doing anything wrong here?

```
 val df = spark.read
    .format("excel")
    .option("sheetNamePattern", section.section_name)
    .option("cellAddress", section.header_start_pos)
    .option("headerRowCount", 1)
    .option("inferSchema","true")
    .option("orientation","ROW")
    .load(path)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark Option: inferSchema vs header = true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56927329/spark-option-inferschema-vs-header-true)

Comment: What Spark SQL package do you use for `excel` format?