# How to specify column types when using spark.write.saveAsTable(tablename) from .csv in pyspark

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to save a new table from a csv. Unfortunately the way the csv is read and saved, all column types are string. The dataset contains other types and I want to specify the types when creating the table.

I have found a solution to alter the column types after creating the table, but it doesnt seem practical.

This is how I create the table:

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

import_path = f"{st_raw}/data.csv"

sparkDF = spark.read.csv(import_path, header=True)

spark.sql(f"CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS {catalog}.{schema}")

tablename = f"{catalog}.{schema}.{table}"
sparkDF.write.saveAsTable(tablename)

assert spark.table(tablename).count() > 0

display(spark.table(tablename))
```

Printing the schema shows, that all columns are of type string:

```
 |-- Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Location: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Country: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Temperature: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CO2 Emissions: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Sea Level Rise: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Precipitation: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Humidity: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Wind Speed: string (nullable = true)
```

I need to specifiy the correct types. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: You can try 2 things, either setting inferSchema 
 to true https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-read-csv-file-into-dataframe/#inferschema. Or to specify the CSV schema explicitly https://docs.databricks.com/en/_extras/notebooks/source/read-csv-schema.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally when reading in a csv, you can use the `inferSchema` option to infer the types of your columns. As is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56927329/spark-option-inferschema-vs-header-true), it is set by defaut to false.
So your initial dataframe should look something like:

```
sparkDF = spark.read.option("inferSchema",True).csv(import_path, header=True)
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, that was the solution to my problem. The inferSchema option worked perfectly and assigned the correct datatypes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you are reading the CSV you can specify the schema with the [schema function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.schema.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.schema).  That link has a full example.