# spark read: Input Size/Records - Its shows double the actual csv file size/no of records

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a csv file, which is nearly 965MB.

As the maximum partition size for splittable sources is 128MB, it should be partitioned to 965/128 = 7.5== 8 partitions.

After the read i checked the number of partitions, they are 8 only. But then why 16 tasks are run for reading 8 partitions.

When i checked the spark UI, it looks that the spark is reading double the size of the csv file. Its reading twice.

[image]

the code is am running is:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

from pyspark.sql.functions import spark_partition_id

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("test").getOrCreate()

print("Spark Version:",spark.version)

sc = spark.sparkContext

print('Master :',sc.master)

print('Default Parallelism :',sc.defaultParallelism)

print('AQE Enabled :',spark.conf.get('spark.sql.adaptive.enabled'))

spark.conf.set('spark.sql.adaptive.enabled','true')

print('AQE Enabled :',spark.conf.get('spark.sql.adaptive.enabled'))

df = spark.read.load("/home/hadoop/sample.csv",format="csv", sep=",", inferSchema="true", header="true")

print('No of partitions in the dataframe :',df.rdd.getNumPartitions())

print(sc.uiWebUrl)

print("Spark Version:",spark.version)

print('Master :',sc.master)

input("Press enter to terminate")

spark.stop()
```

Comment: Maybe because of `inferSchema="true"`? Could you try supplying a schema yourself?

Comment: thanks, thats the correct answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56933052/2897115  ` This requires an extra pass over the file which will result in reading a file with inferSchema set to true being slower.`